# Why there are different request definition for one wsdl

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have been provided a WSDL by client at the beginning of the project, I ended up creating a request and response objects for given WSDL using SOAP UI, where the request object would look as follows,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:def="http://DefaultNamespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <def:someOperation soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <in0 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">SOME_DATA</in0>
      </def:someOperation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But when the actual request coming from the production environment for the same wsdl is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <someOperation xmlns="urn:SOMEService">
    <in0>SOME_DATA</in0>
    </someOperation>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If you observed the name spaces are the same but it does has difference for names like in 1st request its  `<soapenv:Envelope` and same in the 2nd request is `<soap:Envelope` in each node of xml, the definition of operation is also different in both the request in 1st it is,

```
<def:someOperation soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <in0 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">SOME_DATA</in0>
      </def:someOperation>
```

and in 2nd it is,

```
<someOperation xmlns="urn:SOMEService">
    <in0>SOME_DATA</in0>
    </someOperation>
```

I do not know why the interpretation is different, and is it safe to have to change from 1st to 2nd.
IN both the cases actual operation is working fine I do not have any issues with that, it is just cant able to figure out reason of difference.

Could somebody please assist me with this or any direction to a document which could clarify my doubt would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it does has difference for names like in 1st request its  `<soapenv:Envelope` and same in the 2nd request is `<soap:Envelope` in each node of xml

Here `soapenv` and `soap` are `local prefix names` of `namespace=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`. Hence, logically both are same and has no difference.

> the definition of operation is also different in both the request in **1st** v/s **2nd**

In case of 1st, `def:someOperation` XML nodes belongs to namespace = `xmlns:def="http://DefaultNamespace"`

And in 2nd case, name space "urn:SOMEService" is directly defined with `XML Nodes` So
if `DefaultNamespace` is exactly same as `SOMEService`, the it means both of the XML Operation XMLs are same.

Hence,
soapenv v/s soap are same in your case.

Operations, you could conclude based on actual value of `SOMEService` v/s `DefaultNamespace`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your reply, it is very helpful to understand :) But does that mean  SOAP ui generates more of general requests? Like SOMEService is given in the wsdl and SOAP UI is not including it while developing the request from wsdl

Comment: @tyro good to know it helped, I'm less experienced on `SOAP-UI` so not sure if it does ignore the `xml` prefixes, in your case I see, you said, it has `DefaultNamespace` generated by SOAP-UI. Xmls structure bit `flexisible` in the sense of where to define namespaces, at the `root`, immediately on the `node` or at `everynode` but if defined properly, it may have exact same meaning in all the cases, see example here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp